# Transfer folder and subfolders using ChannelSftp in JSch?

Tags: java, sftp, jsch

I want to transfer a folder and a subfolder using JSch `ChannelSftp`. I can successfully transfer files using `channelsftp.put(src, dest)` command but this does not work for folders (at least I could not make it work). So can someone please explain how can I transfer folders and subfolders using `ChannelSftp`?

Answer (score 14):

To work with multilevel folder structures in jsch you:

1. enter them;
2. list their contents;
3. do smth with every found item;
4. repeat 1, 2 & 3 if subfolder is found.

DOWNLOAD dirs method inside your JSCH class:

```
public void downloadDir(String sourcePath, String destPath) throws SftpException { // With subfolders and all files.
    // Create local folders if absent.
    try {
        new File(destPath).mkdirs();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error at : " + destPath);
    }
    sftpChannel.lcd(destPath);

    // Copy remote folders one by one.
    lsFolderCopy(sourcePath, destPath); // Separated because loops itself inside for subfolders.
}

private void lsFolderCopy(String sourcePath, String destPath) throws SftpException { // List source (remote, sftp) directory and create a local copy of it - method for every single directory.
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel.ls(sourcePath); // List source directory structure.
    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry oListItem : list) { // Iterate objects in the list to get file/folder names.
        if (!oListItem.getAttrs().isDir()) { // If it is a file (not a directory).
            if (!(new File(destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename())).exists() || (oListItem.getAttrs().getMTime() > Long.valueOf(new File(destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename()).lastModified() / (long) 1000).intValue())) { // Download only if changed later.
                new File(destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename());
                sftpChannel.get(sourcePath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename(), destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename()); // Grab file from source ([source filename], [destination filename]).
            }
        } else if (!(".".equals(oListItem.getFilename()) || "..".equals(oListItem.getFilename()))) {
            new File(destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename()).mkdirs(); // Empty folder copy.
            lsFolderCopy(sourcePath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename(), destPath + "/" + oListItem.getFilename()); // Enter found folder on server to read its contents and create locally.
        }
    }
}
```

REMOVE dirs method inside your JSCH class:

```
try {
    sftpChannel.cd(dir);
    Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = sftpChannel.ls(dir); // List source directory structure.
    for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry oListItem : list) { // Iterate objects in the list to get file/folder names.
        if (!oListItem.getAttrs().isDir()) { // If it is a file (not a directory).
            sftpChannel.rm(dir + "/" + oListItem.getFilename()); // Remove file.
        } else if (!(".".equals(oListItem.getFilename()) || "..".equals(oListItem.getFilename()))) { // If it is a subdir.
            try {
                sftpChannel.rmdir(dir + "/" + oListItem.getFilename());  // Try removing subdir.
            } catch (Exception e) { // If subdir is not empty and error occurs.
                lsFolderRemove(dir + "/" + oListItem.getFilename()); // Do lsFolderRemove on this subdir to enter it and clear its contents.
            }
        }
    }
    sftpChannel.rmdir(dir); // Finally remove the required dir.
} catch (SftpException sftpException) {
    System.out.println("Removing " + dir + " failed. It may be already deleted.");
}
```

CALL these methods from outside like:

```
MyJSCHClass sftp = new MyJSCHClass();
sftp.removeDir("/mypublic/myfolders");
sftp.disconnect(); // Disconnecting is obligatory - otherwise changes on server can be discarded (e.g. loaded folder disappears).
```

Answer (score 5):

Above code(by zon) works for download as per my understanding.I need to upload to a remote server.I wrote below code to achieve the same.Please try and comment if any issue(it ignores files starting with ".")

```
private static void lsFolderCopy(String sourcePath, String destPath,
            ChannelSftp sftpChannel) throws SftpException,   FileNotFoundException {
    File localFile = new File(sourcePath);

if(localFile.isFile())
{

    //copy if it is a file
    sftpChannel.cd(destPath);

    if(!localFile.getName().startsWith("."))
    sftpChannel.put(new FileInputStream(localFile), localFile.getName(),ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
}   
else{
    System.out.println("inside else "+localFile.getName());
    File[] files = localFile.listFiles();

    if(files!=null && files.length > 0 && !localFile.getName().startsWith("."))
    {

        sftpChannel.cd(destPath);
        SftpATTRS  attrs = null;

    //check if the directory is already existing
    try {
        attrs = sftpChannel.stat(destPath+"/"+localFile.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(destPath+"/"+localFile.getName()+" not found");
    }

    //else create a directory   
    if (attrs != null) {
        System.out.println("Directory exists IsDir="+attrs.isDir());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Creating dir "+localFile.getName());
        sftpChannel.mkdir(localFile.getName());
    }

    //System.out.println("length " + files.length);

     for(int i =0;i<files.length;i++) 
        {

         lsFolderCopy(files[i].getAbsolutePath(),destPath+"/"+localFile.getName(),sftpChannel);

                    }

                }
            }

         }
```

Comment: JSCH is for remote connection. To work with local filesystem you would ruther utilise java.io.File class. But you can try connecting your localhost as if it were a remote one as well.

Comment: Zon.. this code I posted is was to upload to a remote system... (This code was used to upload a ear file from developer box to server box- sort of automatically using jenkins..)

Comment: This is excellent code and working fine. but what if i want to copy files starting with dot(.) as well. After commenting that line, Still its not copying the same?

Comment: Yes it should.. try commenting this line out : if(!localFile.getName().startsWith("."))

Answer (score 0):

From: http://the-project.net16.net/Projekte/projekte/Projekte/Programmieren/sftp-synchronisierung.html

```html
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Vector;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp;
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry;
import com.jcraft.jsch.SftpException;

public class FileMaster {
 public boolean FileAction;
 public File local;
 public String serverDir;
 public ChannelSftp channel;
 
 public FileMaster(boolean copyOrDelete, File local, String to, ChannelSftp channel){
  this.FileAction = copyOrDelete;
  this.local = local;
  this.serverDir = to;
  this.channel = channel;
 }
 
 /*
  * If FileAction = true, the File local is copied to the serverDir, else the file is deleted.
  */
 public void runMaster() throws FileNotFoundException, SftpException{
  if(FileAction){
   copy(local, serverDir, channel);
  } else { 
   delete(serverDir, channel);
  }
 }
 
 /*
  * Copies recursive
  */
 public static void copy(File localFile, String destPath, ChannelSftp clientChannel) throws SftpException, FileNotFoundException{
  if(localFile.isDirectory()){
   clientChannel.mkdir(localFile.getName());
   GUI.addToConsole("Created Folder: " + localFile.getName() + " in " + destPath);

   destPath = destPath + "/" + localFile.getName();
   clientChannel.cd(destPath);
   
   for(File file: localFile.listFiles()){
    copy(file, destPath, clientChannel);
   }
   clientChannel.cd(destPath.substring(0, destPath.lastIndexOf('/')));
  } else {
   GUI.addToConsole("Copying File: " + localFile.getName() + " to " + destPath);
   clientChannel.put(new FileInputStream(localFile), localFile.getName(),ChannelSftp.OVERWRITE);
  }

 }
 
 /*
  * File/Folder is deleted, but not recursive
  */
 public void delete(String filename, ChannelSftp sFTPchannel) throws SftpException{  
  if(sFTPchannel.stat(filename).isDir()){
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   Vector<LsEntry> fileList = sFTPchannel.ls(filename);
   sFTPchannel.cd(filename);
   int size = fileList.size();
   for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if(!fileList.get(i).getFilename().startsWith(".")){
     delete(fileList.get(i).getFilename(), sFTPchannel);
    }
   }
   sFTPchannel.cd("..");
   sFTPchannel.rmdir(filename);
  } else {
   sFTPchannel.rm(filename.toString());
  }
  GUI.addToConsole("Deleted: " + filename + " in " + sFTPchannel.pwd());
 }

}
```