# Download directory content from SFTP server recursively

Tags: scala, sftp, jsch

How do we download directory content from SFTP server recursively in Scala? Can someone please help me with an example?

```
def recursiveDirectoryDownload(sourcePath: String, destinationPath: String) : Unit = { 
  val fileAndFolderList = channelSftp.ls(sourcePath) 
  for(item <- fileAndFolderList)
  { 
    if(! item.getAttrs.isDir)
    { 
      ChannelSftp.get(sourcePath + “\” + item.getFilename,destinationPath +”\” + item.getFilename) 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this code but not sure how do we download data from directory.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call back your `recursiveDirectoryDownload` function, when you encounter a subfolder.

See this question for implementation in Java:
[Transfer folder and subfolders using channelsftp in JSch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11650013/850848)
It should be trivial to translate to Scala.